# Binomial regression with non traditional dataset

Tags: regression, logistic

I am aiming to do a binomial regression, most aspects are close to textbook situations.
But not on the datasets side, while I have a traditional dataset, that will split into training, test and validation. I also have a dataset which is more a nice to have (in linear programming / operational research, I would consider it as an additional goal but not the objective of the optimisation), so that if the values do not align with what is in the traditional dataset I would not want them to influence the results.

I am thinking to use weighted (sample weights) regression to indicate that data in the nice to have dataset is less reliable so that they influence less the results. However, this does not appear as a very neat approach to me. As it feels like OLS solving is inadequate for the nice to have dataset.

Are there better or more standard ways to tackle this type of problem?

-- EDIT
in light of the comment: I can think of an example to illustrate (although the dice below is maybe sufficient).
Say we are talking about a binomial regression answering a question like: given the length of a word what is the probability of the word containing an "e". In the traditional data set, I would have sampled words from English 18th-century poetry as I know the model will be used exclusively on English 18th-century poetry. In the nice to have I have a dump from English and German Wikipedia.
Now when I look at 5 letter words it would make sense to look exclusively at the traditional dataset, because the other dataset won't bring better data. But If I have a 19 letter word, it could be interesting to benefit from the German's words so that if some poet used some German word or uncommon english words that I might have found in the 18th-century poetry.
Of course the problem is more complex, there more independent variables, and hence a complete analysis would be time-consuming. And having in mind the limited advantage we could get from the nice to have dataset it is difficult to get in that direction.

Comment: Just for clarification: are you trying to combine two different datasets into one (on which you plan to perform a binomial regression), but you suspect that the data in one of the two datasets might not be as reliable as the other? I'm not sure if I can answer your question, but it would be probably informative for other people to mention why you suspect that the "nice to have" dataset is less reliable.

Comment: The traditional one is data collected about the population of interest. The nice to have is not transparent exactly of which population is sampled from. The assumption is that it is a mixture of several populations that share some characteristics with our population of interest. Say we sample from a biased 6 sides dice, and they sample from another 6 (or 7 for all we know) sides dice with a different bias. Hence if the dataset informs on space we do not have in our data, then it is better than nothing, but if we have something in our set then the nice to have is irrelevant.